# How to use while loop inside subshell after pipe

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have looked and looked for a solution to this, but I can't find anything that directly addresses my problem. I'm trying to add up the lines added and removed by certain authors in a git repo. I'm using git log piped to sed piped to awk which I am now trying to pipe to a subshell to add up the numbers. The issue is that the piped input isn't getting interpreted properly in the subshell, and I can't figure out why. I suspect it's in the while-loop, because of the nature of subshell syntax and its pickiness with semicolons.

I've moved around the code inside the subshell, added and removed semicolons, used backslashes for line separation to see if that was the issue, and none of it has worked. I'm not well-versed in shell so it could be a glaringly obvious issue to someone who is more experienced. "$author" is just the nth positional parameter from the command-line.

```sh
for author; do
        echo "Listing file and line changes for $author"
        git log --shortstat --author="$author" ${date:+--since="$date"} \
        | sed -n -e '/files\? changed/s/, /\n/gp' \
        | awk '
            $3=="changed"       {changed+=$1}
            $2=="deletions(-)"  {deletions+=$1}
            $2=="insertions(+)" {insertions+=$1}
            END{
                print "files changed:", changed,
                    " lines removed:", deletions,
                    " lines added:", insertions,
                    " net change:", insertions-deletions
            }'
done | {
      total_changed=0
      total_added=0
      total_removed=0
      while read changed insertions deletions; do
        let total_changed+=changed
        let total_added+=insertions
        let total_removed+=deletions
      done
      echo "totals:"
      echo "files changed: $total_changed"
      echo "lines added: $total_added"
      echo "lines removed: $total_removed" ;
    }
```

The last part should output the totals but instead they output 0. I also get some weird syntax errors. Here's the output (input is "Benjamin Hills):

```
    /home/bhills/./git-log-lines-removed.sh: line 65: let: and line changes for Benjamin Hills: syntax error in expression (error token is "line changes for Benjamin Hills")
    /home/bhills/./git-log-lines-removed.sh: line 64: let: changed:: syntax error in expression (error token is ":")
    /home/bhills/./git-log-lines-removed.sh: line 65: let: 61  lines removed: 1345  lines added: 246  net change: -1099: syntax error in expression (error token is "lines removed: 1345  lines added: 246  net change: -1099")
    totals:
    files changed: 0
    lines added: 0
    lines removed: 0
```

Comment: Here's an easier way to reproduce your problem: `var="Listing file and line changes for $author"; let total+=var`

Comment: @thatotherguy see that's not what I want in terms of input. I want the input to be changed, insertions, and deletions.

Comment: Makes sense. Since the input to your `while read` loop is the output of your `for` loop, you should change your `for` loop to output the format you want

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.

Comment: Your first "for" loop formats data in a format nice to read for a human being, but difficult to parse with a shell one liner.

Comment: Run the "for ... done" loop in your script alone (without the "| { ... }" part) to view what I mean.

Comment: My advice is : use a dumber output format in the first "for" loop, then, using awk for example, write a script which formats data per author, and also stores incremental counters to display the "end" line

Comment: a "dumber format" can be : "changed:insertions:deletions:author name" ; then you can "awk -F':' '{ ... } END { ... }'" through the output

Comment: If you used a process substitution to get content out of `git log` you could have the parent shell directly consume it (setting variables that aren't scoped to a subshell at all), avoiding getting into this mess in the first place. See the suggestions in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: What percentage of your total commits will be made by one of the authors on your command line? (If that percentage is a large one, it'll be much faster to run `git log` only once and collect the author names as part of the output; `--format` can put them on the same line as the numbers you want).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't realize that I could format the output using a flag on `git log`, the commits will be spread between four or five authors.

Comment: Note that you're relying on a bunch of non-POSIX features, btw. `let` for example? Not POSIX; the POSIX math syntax is `total_changed=$(( total_changed + changed ))` to do an in-place addition. (Yes, `let` is *old*, but that doesn't mean it's *standard-compliant*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to generate human-readable output **twice**: Once in awk, another time in bash. Since the output `awk` generates is input to `bash`, that means you're trying to pipe an output format meant for humans and read it as if it were an input format meant for machines; obviously, it's not.

There's no good reason to take that approach at all: Generate *all* your human-readable output in the same process.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh

total_changed=0
total_deletions=0
total_insertions=0

for author; do
  changed=0; deletions=0; insertions=0

  # Loop over output from "git log" for a single author
  while read added deleted _; do
    (( ++changed )) # each line is a file changed
    { [[ $added = - ]] || [[ $deleted = - ]]; } && continue # skip binary files
    (( insertions += added ))
    (( deletions += deleted ))
  done < <(git log --numstat --format='' --author="$author" ${date:+--since="$date"})

  # Print results from that author
  printf '%s\n' "For author: $author" \
                "  Files changed: $changed" \
                "  Deletions: $deletions" \
                "  Insertions: $insertions"

  # Add to totals
  (( total_changed+=changed ))
  (( total_deletions+=deletions ))
  (( total_insertions+=insertions ))
done

# Print those totals
printf '%s\n' "Totals:" \
              "  Files changed: $total_changed" \
              "  Deletions: $total_deletions" \
              "  Insertions: $total_insertions"
```

Comment: I realize now the output I'm feeding. Originally the script was intended for listing on a per author basis without totaling, but then I wanted to implement totaling, and added the last pipe. That's why I'm feeding human-readable output into the last pipe. Tried to add a new feature without restructuring. I'll try incorporating your suggestion into my script.

Comment: If you're no longer intending to run it on a per-author basis, I'd change the `--format` line to print the author; update the parsing bits to recognize lines with that data and use it to store your counters in associative arrays keyed by author, and then you can run `git log` only once, and still collect breakouts with each author's stats individually.

Comment: The only thing is I want to just write a POSIX compliant shell script and avoid using things specific to bash for the sake of portability.

Comment: Portability is overrated -- if process substitutions and comparable features didn't let you write correct code in ways that baseline POSIX shells don't permit, they wouldn't exist. Not kidding at all, there -- POSIX sh, as of the 2018 version of the standard, just isn't expressive enough to let you use shell to write a whole lot of useful things (dealing with filenames with NULs is one of those major cases).